# Parsing dictionary and grouping output with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

Let's say I have a

```
dictionary = {
              'host_type' : {'public_ip':['ip_address','ip_address','ip_address'], 
                             'private_dns':['dns_name','dns_name','dns_name']} 
              }
```

There are some host types, let's say there are 3 host types: master,slave,backup

The output from the dictionary can contain different amount of hosts for each host type. For example, for 2 masters, 6 slaves, 2 backups the dictionary would look like this:

```
dictionary = 
   {
    'master' : {
                'public_ip':['ip_address','ip_address'], 
                'private_dns': ['dns_name','dns_name']
               },
    'slave' : {
               'public_ip':['ip_address','ip_address', 'ip_address','ip_address','ip_address','ip_address'], 
               'private_dns': ['dns_name','dns_name','dns_name','dns_name','dns_name','dns_name']
              },
    'backup' : {
                'public_ip':['ip_address','ip_address'],
                'private_dns':['dns_name','dns_name']
               }
    }
```

Now I want to parse the dictionary and group the hosts in such way that I always have 1 master, 1 backup, 3 slaves. How can I parse such dictionary to achieve similar effect:

```
master,public_ip,private_dns
backup,public_ip,private_dns
slave,public_ip,private_dns
slave,public_ip,private_dns
slave,public_ip,private_dns

master,public_ip,private_dns
backup,public_ip,private_dns
slave,public_ip,private_dns
slave,public_ip,private_dns
slave,public_ip,private_dns
```

Comment: I tried a grouper function so I got the output in form: 
(public_ip, private_dns) But still I need to group that by 1master,1backup,3slaves

Comment: I don't need an exact answer but maybe a hint to put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {
'master' : {
            'public_ip':['ip_address0M','ip_address1M'], 
            'private_dns': ['dns_name','dns_name']
           },
'slave' : {
           'public_ip':['ip_address0s','ip_address1s', 'ip_address2s','ip_address3s','ip_address4s','ip_address5s'], 
           'private_dns': ['dns_name','dns_name','dns_name','dns_name','dns_name','dns_name']
          },
'backup' : {
            'public_ip':['ip_address0b','ip_address1b'],
            'private_dns':['dns_name','dns_name']
           }
}


masterCount = 0
slavecount = 0
backupCount = 0

result = list()

while(masterCount + 1 <= len(d['master']['public_ip']) and slavecount + 3 <= len(d['slave']['public_ip']) and backupCount + 1 <= len(d['backup']['public_ip'])):
    result.append([])
    tempList = [d['master']['public_ip'][masterCount], d['slave']['public_ip'][slavecount:slavecount+3], d['backup']['public_ip'][backupCount]]
    result[masterCount].append(tempList)
    masterCount+=1
    slavecount+=3
    backupCount==1

print(result)
```

Now result is of the format:

1. result[index][0] is master
2. result[index][1] is slave
3. result[index][2] is backup

[EDIT]
You can do something similar to add the DNS. I have not added it as you mentioned you only wanted the directions.

Output:

```
[[['ip_address0M', ['ip_address0s', 'ip_address1s', 'ip_address2s'], 'ip_address0b']], [['ip_address1M', ['ip_address3s', 'ip_address4s', 'ip_address5s'], 'ip_address0b']]]
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. Ive done it bit different but your answer got me on the tracks. Thanks. I approve it as the answer

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

```
m1 = d['master']['public']
m2 = d['master']['private']
b1 = d['backup']['public']
b2 = d['backup']['private']
s1 = d['slave']['public']
s2 = d['slave']['private']

zip(zip(m1, m2), zip(b1, b2), zip(*[iter(zip(s1, s2))]*3))
```

There's probably a better solution for resolving all the lists from the dictionary, but this should work.